# How to use SignalR in ASP.NET Webforms (C#) & Web API for user based notification when Inser/Update/Delete in SQL Server like Facebook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, signalr

I am new to SignalR. I've a ASP.NET web form application & Web API project **(Not Core)**, both are different projects. I need to get notification in web form app when there is any change in a table (SQL Server) like in Facebook. Web app is a user login based so I need to send notification to a specific user.

Should I use SignalR Self Host solution to get notification in website & mobile app or other solution?

Comment: The question is too broad. Try to read basic signalR documentation. There are few alternative solution can be implemented, but it's hard to suggest without digging into your details

Comment: @AnatoliKlamer I've tried it with the basic documentation but no luck